# Incorrect text displayed on reading a text file

Tags: java, text-files

I am writing a program to read a text file. When I am printing the read values, the values are displayed incorrectly.
Text file contains following data

```
This is line one
This is line two
This is line three
This is line four
```

Code to read text file is as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SearchFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Output is as follows:

[image]

Please help to fix this issue. Why am I getting the output displayed as garbage characters.

Comment: The values seem to have some additional encoding.  How did you create the file?  How are you displaying (via a terminal window, IDE console???)

Comment: what's the encoding of the file?

Comment: it is working fine for me.I think encoding problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer look at this link http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

Comment: Values are displayed on Eclipse IDE console

Answer (score 1):

It's an encoding problem, and from the output, it looks like the file is encoded in some UTF-16 variant. Since `FileReader` always uses the platform's default encoding, give this a try:

```
new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream("C:\\IASTATE\\test.txt"), "UTF-16LE"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the reason for your problems but using `FileReader` is usually a bad idea as it **always** uses current platform's default encoding. So in case your file was created with a different encoding it might print out "garbage". You can try doing instead:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\IASTATE\\test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Where you substitute `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` with the encoding of your `test.txt` file.